# Python: Check if files exist and copy only the missing files

Tags: python

I'm a begynder in python and trying to make a script that does the following:

- Check number of files, if they exist in the destFile
- If they all exist, exit the script (don't do anything)
- If some files are missing, copy only the missing files from the srcFile to the destFile

The script that I have made is working, but the issue that I would like your help with is to make my script only copies the file/files missing and not as my script is doing now, which copies from file 1 (test1.txt) to the file missing. Example if test4.txt & test5.txt files are missing in destFile, my script will copy from test1.txt to test5.txt, in stead of only copying the two missing files test4.txt & test5.txt.

```
import os, shutil 
from datetime import datetime
count = 0
error = "ERROR! file is missing! (files have been copied)"
sttime = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S - ')
os.chdir("C:\log") 
log = "log.txt"
srcFile = [r"C:\srcFile\test1.txt", 
           r"C:\srcFile\test2.txt",
           r"C:\srcFile\test3.txt",
           r"C:\srcFile\test4.txt",
           r"C:\srcFile\test5.txt"]

destFile = [r"C:\destFile\test1.txt", 
            r"C:\destFile\test2.txt",
            r"C:\destFile\test3.txt",
            r"C:\destFile\test4.txt",
            r"C:\destFile\test5.txt"]
for file in destFile:
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        for file_sr in srcFile:
            if not os.path.exists(file): 
                shutil.copy(file_sr, 'C:\destFile')
        count +=1                   
        with open(log, 'a') as logfile:
                logfile.write(sttime + error + " " + str(count) + " => " + file + '\n')
```

Comment: Do you consider src/test1 and dest/test1 to be paired, so if dest/test1 is missing, you want to copy src/test1 ? (and so on with other files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're iterating over *all* of the source files whenever you detect a missing destination file: `for file_sr in srcFile:`. Instead, you can copy *just* the missing file by keeping track of the position (in the array) of the missing destination file:

```
for position, file in enumerate(destFile):
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        file_sr = srcFile[position]
        if not os.path.exists(file): 
            shutil.copy(file_sr, 'C:\destFile')
```

Comment: you could also use `zip` : `for src, dest in zip(srcFIle, destFile):`

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, you can do:

```
import os, shutil 
from datetime import datetime
count = 0
error = "ERROR! file is missing! (files have been copied)"
sttime = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S - ')
os.chdir("C:\log") 
log = "log.txt"
srcFile = [r"C:\srcFile\test1.txt", 
           r"C:\srcFile\test2.txt",
           r"C:\srcFile\test3.txt",
           r"C:\srcFile\test4.txt",
           r"C:\srcFile\test5.txt"]

destFile = [r"C:\destFile\test1.txt", 
            r"C:\destFile\test2.txt",
            r"C:\destFile\test3.txt",
            r"C:\destFile\test4.txt",
            r"C:\destFile\test5.txt"]
for file in destFile:
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        src_file = destFile.replace("destFile","srcFile")
        shutil.copy(src_file, file)
        count +=1                   
        with open(log, 'a') as logfile:
            logfile.write(sttime + error + " " + str(count) + " => " + file + '\n')
```

Comment: this would work only if source and destination folders are always named the same (and in this case, you'd better work only with filename and prepend them source/destination directory names when needed)

Comment: Thanks for recalling the obvious :). As you may see, the way the code of the questionner is made is single use anyway. You don't use a list with hard coded filenames in that situation. You glob the source in a list, check the dest, etc. That's just a functional minimal change correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help guys. Exactly my problem was that I was iterating over all of the source files whenever I detected a missing destination file. The following logic from mackorone is doing what I was looking for.

```
for position, file in enumerate(destFile):
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        file_sr = srcFile[position]
        shutil.copy(file_sr, 'C:\destFile')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the script, so now this script compares two folders, source folder and destination folder. If destination folder is missing files from the source folder, it will be copied. The script is working fine.

```
import os
import shutil
from datetime import datetime

sttime = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S - ')
error = "ERROR! file is missing! (files have been copied)"

des_path = 'C:\des_folder'
sr_path = 'C:\sr_folder'

des_folder = os.listdir(des_path)
sr_folder = os.listdir(sr_path)
count = 0
os.chdir("C:\log") 
log = "log.txt"

def compare_folder(folder1,folder2):
    files_in_sr_folder = set(sr_folder) - set(des_folder)
    return files_in_sr_folder

files_missing = compare_folder(sr_folder,des_folder)

if len(files_missing) != 0:
    for file in files_missing:
        full_path_files = os.path.join(sr_path,file)
        shutil.copy(full_path_files,des_path)
        count +=1
        with open(log, 'a') as logfile:
            logfile.write(sttime + error + " " + str(count) + " => " + file + '\n')
else:
    exit
```